# ssh session open request is giving EOF eventually on ssh connection

Tags: go, networking, design-patterns, ssh, agent

I work on agent demon which runs on a node. When we start the agent, all the ssh connections to the other nodes are built and later on at particular time intervals(weekly once) we create new sessions on these ssh connections to communicate with the other nodes. but it has been observed that after 1 month around the time frame, the session creation would give EOF error.

```
      User: config.Username,
      Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
         ssh.Password(config.Password),
      },
      HostKeyCallback: func(hostname string, remote net.Addr, key ssh.PublicKey) error {
         return nil
      },
}
client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", config.Host+":22", sshConfig)
```

```
session, err := client.NewSession()
defer session.Close()
b, err := session.CombinedOutput(command)
```

When this session creation gives EOF error, is there any way to get back the ssh connection in working state?

If I consider redialing or reconnect when only if I get error on read/write then which design pattren will be useful here.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried sending ssh keepalive messages?

Comment: yup. I feel it is not connection timeout. still problem persists.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is connection getting broken after sometime, a few things you can try is

1. Create a mechanism to keep the connection alive if the server provides with an api or ping to increase connection expire time. like [github.com/felixge/tcpkeepalive](http://github.com/felixge/tcpkeepalive)
2. Or Try re dialing the connection at a fixed time interval.

Comment: Thanks for the help. As it is customer env, I don't have access to change connection expire time. but definitely can think of redialing at a fixed time intervals

Comment: No the tcpkeepalive keeps sending packets on connection to keep it from closing when not in use, so no change needed on customer side